# Python: how can I merge two dataframes on two column keys?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I tried to merge two dataframes on two column keys using merge function but it returns with NaN for some rows. I am not sure what's wrong. Could you please advise what's the issue? Thank you!

df1

```
             VR Ccy_1 Ccy_2 Qualifier     Ccy_Gp1     Ccy_Gp2
0  2.864298e+08   BRL   KRW    BRLKRW  Category 2  Category 2
1  9.547661e+08   BRL   USD    BRLUSD  Category 2  Category 1
2  1.145719e+08   CNY   SGD    CNYSGD  Category 2  Category 2
3 -3.819065e+08   EUR   QAR    EURQAR  Category 1  Category 3
4  1.183910e+09   GBP   USD    GBPUSD  Category 1  Category 1
5 -1.432149e+08   HKD   KRW    HKDKRW  Category 2  Category 2
6 -1.145719e+08   RUB   TRY    RUBTRY  Category 2  Category 2
```

df2

```
       Ccy_Gp1      Ccy_Gp2  Vega Concentration threshold (USD)
0   Category 1   Category 1                          3900000000
1  Category 1    Category 2                          1400000000
2  Category 1    Category 3                           640000000
3   Category 2   Category 2                           690000000
4   Category 2   Category 3                           440000000
5  Category 3    Category 3                           280000000
6   Category 2  Category 1                           1400000000
7   Category 3  Category 1                            640000000
8   Category 3   Category 2                           440000000
```

Here's my code

```
df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Ccy_Gp1','Ccy_Gp2'], how='left')
```

the returned dataframe

```
             VR Ccy_1 Ccy_2 Qualifier     Ccy_Gp1     Ccy_Gp2  Vega Concentration threshold (USD)
0  2.864298e+08   BRL   KRW    BRLKRW  Category 2  Category 2                        6.900000e+08
1  9.547661e+08   BRL   USD    BRLUSD  Category 2  Category 1                                 NaN
2  1.145719e+08   CNY   SGD    CNYSGD  Category 2  Category 2                        6.900000e+08
3 -3.819065e+08   EUR   QAR    EURQAR  Category 1  Category 3                                 NaN
4  1.183910e+09   GBP   USD    GBPUSD  Category 1  Category 1                        3.900000e+09
5 -1.432149e+08   HKD   KRW    HKDKRW  Category 2  Category 2                        6.900000e+08
6 -1.145719e+08   RUB   TRY    RUBTRY  Category 2  Category 2                        6.900000e+08
```

Comment: That means for that specific roe in `df1` there is no match in `df2` for `'Ccy_Gp1','Ccy_Gp2`

Comment: Check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html it might be helpful to understand how merge works. Maybe you are looking for how='inner'

Comment: for ```Category 2  Category 1``` and ```Category 1  Category 3``` combinations, they should be able to match with df2 on these two keys?  I wonder if this is due to formatting issue cos the data in column 'Ccy_Gp1` and `Ccy_Gp2` are not aligned on the line

Comment: @Cryckx I have tried to use inner but it doesn't work either

Comment: Could you print the entire dataframe with `print(df.to_string())`

Comment: @Cryckx Sure, I just put the entire dataframe in my question

Comment: Okay you're right the formatting issue probably matters ^^ it seems you have a white space or something  before the key

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like that to remove the whitespaces from the column 'Ccy_Gp1' in df2 before doing the merge :

```
df2['Ccy_Gp1'] = df2['Ccy_Gp1'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip())
```

Comment: I used the code to remove the whitespaces from both columns `Ccy_Gp1` and `Ccy_Gp2` but they still don't merge well